# java Future inconsistent get() return value

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice

Please help me. I don't know what I'm doing anymore.

Problem is return value of future.get(); is inconsistent.
Results are sometimes (valid and valid),(valid and null), (null and valid)

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
        ConfigParameter.HTML_TO_PDF_CONVERTER_MAX_THREADS.getPropertyValue(20));
Set<Callable<String>> workers = new LinkedHashSet<>();

System.out.println("values to process: " + values.size());
for (String serviceId : values) {
    workers.add(new HtmlInvoiceNMIPdfWorker(dir, customer, serviceId, stmtno,
            html_invoice_id, groupno, htmlconverter_cmd, size));
}

System.out.println("Workers: " + workers.size());

// run threads
List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(workers);
System.out.println("Futures.size(): " + futures.size());

// get worker results
for (Future<String> future : futures) {
    System.out.println("Futures: " + future.get());
    String file = future.get();

    if (!StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty(file)) {
        System.out.println("filenames.add(file): " + file);
        filenames.add(file);
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }

}

executorService.shutdown();
```

One of the print result:

```
value to process: 2
Workers: 2
Futures.size(): 2
Futures: null
Futures: 32000_1367_20181119182612.pdf
filenames.add(file): 32000_1367_20181119182612.pdf
```

I am new to threading. I've read multiple stackoverflow questions and still don't know the reason.

Edit: Added part of the callable as it's a big method.
getInvoice() assembles html section of the invoices from Database based on settings. The HTML will then be converted to PDF for download.

```
String html="<html>";
html += "<head>";
html += "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">";
html += "<style>@font-face {font-family: 'ocr-b_10_btregular'; src: url('assets/font/tt0646m-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('assets/font/tt0646m-webfont.woff') format('woff'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;}</style>";
html += "</head>";
html += "<body>";
html += getInvoice(custno, stmtno,nmiServiceId, html_invoice_id, wsReplacePath, groupno);
html += "</body>";
return convertToPDF(html,destination,custno,stmtno,html_invoice_id,groupno,null,cmd);
```

Comment: Can you post source of the Callable?

Comment: Hi @Meini, updated the question with the callable code.

Comment: additional info. when in debug mode, everything is correct.

Comment: Affecting behavior by debugging is pretty typical for concurrency problems (Heisenbug). I didn't test it but the use of `ExecutorService` seems correct. The problem is most propably in the `Callable` itself. There might be some mutable shared resources between multiple threads, perhaps one of the construction parameters.

Comment: Looks like `HtmlInvoiceNMIPdfWorker` (the callable) returns `null`. The code you added returns the result of `convertToPDF()` so we need to see what's in there, too.

Comment: Hi @Meini, Michel, Thank you so much for your inputs. Problem is in the Callable. Converting the HTML to PDF is dependent on the filename+timestamp, when a PDF file exist, the HTML will not be converted. But since I am creating 2+ files with almost the same timestamp, the other file will be ignored.